# Enable programmatically focus on text field inside phonegap running on Android

Tags: android, webkit, cordova

I call textFieldElement.focus() inside my phonegap Android app but the keyboard is not slide up after that. Can you guy help with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you tried `editText.requestFocus()` ?

Comment: I'm talking about an input inside an html page rendered by phonegap. Does it has `#requestFocus()`?

Comment: Inside my Activity onCreate, I have `this.appView.requestFocus()` already but then calling `textFieldElement.focus()` within the webview doesn't work (show the keyboard) neither.

Comment: Thanks a million for the plugin. For others who want to use it: Visit this link; http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.plugin.softkeyboard Or install it straight away: $ cordova add plugin org.apache.cordova.plugin.softkeyboard && cordova build && cordova prepare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's know. You can work around this in android by writeing native java code as plugin to programaticaly show softkeyboard.  [**Here are few hints**](http://www.x-services.nl/control-soft-keyboard-on-android-2-2-device-in-phonegap-cordova-application/311)

Comment: Okay, I'll see to writing plugin for Phonegap and report back.

Comment: I finally managed to get this work. A plugin has been committed by Justin Wark a while ago that does exactly that job: `https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/SoftKeyboard/SoftKeyBoard.java`. Currently, I call both `input.focus()`, then simulate the `click` event and then `SoftKeyBoard.showKeyBoard()`

Comment: Finally use the plugin here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard and... it works!

Answer (score 1):

you have to set KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction to false in your config.xml

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code to focus on the edittext.

```
 document.getElementById("yourEditText_id").focus();
```